# Добавить класс ,ID в файл PHP

Tags: php, css, mysql

Народ , как можно записать свой ID или CLASS таблице PHP .по такому принципу :

```
<td><input type="number"class="wr" name="inputc" id="inputc" ></td>
```

только в этом коде

```
'<td>'<?php echo $results->data[$i]['Name']; ?>'</td>'
```

Comment: что вы делаете, откуда и зачем?

Comment: Сейчас постараюсь обьяснить. У меня есть готовая уже таблица в html со стилями ,а мне нужно эту таблицу подключить к базе данных (php my admin) и чтоб можно было прописывать класс ,имя и ID потому что под них подвязана другая информация .

Answer (score 0):

```
'<td>'<?php 
$myclass = 'myclass';
echo preg_replace('/class="(.*)"/U','class="'.$myclass.'"',$results->data[$i]['Name']);
?>'</td>'
```

Comment: А есть еще какие-то варианты ?

Comment: Я просто не понял этот момент '/class="(.*)"/U','class="'

Comment: $myclass - это ваш класс, на который хотите заменить

Comment: Еще вариант 
'<td>'<?php echo str_replace('class="wr"','class="myclass"',$results->data[$i]['Name']); ?>'</td>'
при условии что класс wr не будет изменяться

Comment: Вот , этот вариантик будет по лучше ) спасибо огромное , будем пробовать подключаться )